# Setting If statement for UITextfield to check the entered number and perform action (via UIButton)

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have three `UIText-field`to enter the number below 300 only.After that we have to click on `uibutton` called `calculate`.After click calculate button it will calculate that 3 numbers entered in my `UITex-field` and show the result.

**updated:**

I need to check condition for my `UITextfield` before or after my `calculate` button was press.The value entered in my UITex-field should below 300 only.if the value entered above 300 means any warning or uialert should show.How to do this ?

**This is my three textfield to get number and perform action:**

```
 - (IBAction)calcBtn:(id)sender {

 if ([coffeTf.text <= 300] || [waterTf.text <=300] || [powderTf.text <=300]) {

        UIAlertView *error = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"oops" message:@"You must complete all fields" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [error show];

    }

    else {
        int cofee = [[self.coffeTf text] intValue];
        int water = [[self.waterTf text] intValue];
        int powder = [[self.powderTf text] intValue];


        float cutoff = (CGFloat) cofee/3 + water/3 + powder/2;
        NSLog(@"Result: %f", cutoff);
        NSString *cutmark = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", Result];
        self.resultTf.text = Result;


    }
```

I have updated my post.In my code i used if statement to check ,but i am getting error `Expected identifier`.Thus any code i am missing:

```
 if ([coffeTf.text <= 300] || [waterTf.text <=300] || [powderTf.text <=300]) {

        UIAlertView *error = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"oops" message:@"You must complete all fields" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [error show];

    }

    else {
}
```

Comment: What about `if (cofee >= 300 || water >= 300 || powder >= 300){//show alert}`

Comment: see my update. I have explained in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use textfield delegates, set the delegate for textfields and use the following method (assuming you are only getting numeric values in textfield)

In .h file interface add UITextField delegate

```
yourViewController:UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

In View DidLoad Method add

```
coffeTf.delegate = self;
waterTf.delegate = self;
powderTf.delegate = self;
```

Then just copy paste the following. Do not change anything

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
return [newString intValue] < 300;
}
```

In this way the textfield will never get a value of 300 or above.

Comment: yes thanks its worked.but i also have posted my new code.in that i used with if statement.but i am getting error !

Comment: Instead of [coffeTf.text <= 300], use [[coffeTf.text intValue] <= 300]].